# String sort for buckets in aggregation elastic search

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

I want to sort the result by field that has string value, for example, I have responded like this

```
"aggregations": {
    "group_agg": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": -1,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 82,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "38:16:33:6A:71:FF",
                "doc_count": 1,
                "group_agg_top_hit": {
                    "hits": {
                        "total": 1,
                        "max_score": null,
                        "hits": [
                            {
                                "_index": "23432534534",
                                "_type": "log",
                                "_id": "123143435346",
                                "_score": null,
                                "_source": {
                                    "name1": "aaa-bbb",
                                    "name2": "asdasd-bbb",
                                    "Mac": "38:22:33:6A:71:FF",
                                    "description": "",
                                    "event_timestamp": "2017-12-16T08:06:10.000+0000",
                                    "ssid": "aaa-network"
                                },
                                "sort": [
                                    1513411570000
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "order_agg": {
                    "value": 1513411570000,
                    "value_as_string": "2017-12-16T08:06:10.000Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and I soreted it by time_stamp which is a neumarical value , and I need to sort the results with

======================================

```
 "aggs": {
"group_agg": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "Mac.rawData",
    "size": 1,
     "order" : { "order_agg" : "asc" }   ----> need to change this to make sorting by name 1 or name 2

  },
  "aggs": {
    "order_agg": {
      "max": {
        "field": "event_timestamp"
      }
    },
    "group_agg_top_hit": {
      "top_hits": {
      "sort": [
                {
                    "event_timestamp": {
                        "order": "desc"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "_source": {
                "includes": ["name1", "name2", "Mac", "ssid", "event_timestamp","description"]
            },
        "size": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

====
this code is working but I need to change the bucket sorting to be by name instead of event_timestamp

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ES version > 6.x then you can use Composite Aggregations. It accepts text search, but works a bit different from the TermAggregation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

I too have tried to accomplish this; however, to no avail because all single-value metric aggregations such as `max`, `avg`, etc. require the field being aggregated to be an `integer` type.

You likely have run into this and are looking for external help like I am; hopefully someone else sees this post of yours and points out an aggregation solution or at least alternatives or best practices that can accomplish sorting buckets by `text` fields.